# How to select "incidents" in network analysis based on their routes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I am using Closest Facility tool in Network analysis to locate closest routes between houses and bus stops.

I am using Length as accumulation attribute to know distance between each house and bus stop. Houses are incidents and bus stops facilities.

When I am done with analysis I can see each route from house to bus stop but I can't find way how to select houses according to their calculated routes. For example I would like to do selection of houses which can reach bus stops with distance no more then 300m.

Since the points of houses are not attaching to road network there is no way how I can do selection based on location. If I would like to do selection based on attributes I can't see any match between attribute tables of "routes" and "incidents".

I guess there must be some way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. You need to join the `Routes` table to the `Incidents` table.

`Routes` sublayer has a field `IncidentID`. This corresponds to the `ObjectID` field in the `Incidents` sublayer.

Now right-click the `Incidents` layer in the TOC > `Joins and Relates` > `Join`. Specify as follows:

1. ObjectID
2. Routes
3. IncidentID

[image]

Now you have joined all the fields from the `Routes` sublayer into the `Incidents`. You will have the accumulated field (eg `Total_Meters`) in the `Incidents` table and you can use the Select By Attributes or Definition Query to limit the features shown/analyzed.

If you don't want to get all of the fields joined, you can use the [Join Field GP tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/join-field.htm) to transfer only the accumulated field.