# How to see only those incidents that cannot reach facilities in ArcGIS Closest Facility analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, closest-facility

I have 373 'incidents' and need to map their routes to their closest hospitals ('facilities') using a flood zone as a 'polygon barrier'

ArcGIS can only route 333 of the 373 because several 'incidents' are within the flood zone and the rest cannot reach their 'facility' because all possible routes have been cut off by the flood zone.

ArcGIS differentiates between those 'incidents' that are within the flood zone, but treats all other 'incidents', even those that *cannot* be routed, as the same (see image). When I check the Attributes there is no info to differentiate them.

**How can I differentiate between those 'incidents' that can reach their 'facility' and those that cannot reach their 'facility' because no route is available?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't perfect, but it got me the results:

I followed the advice from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186061/how-to-select-incidents-in-network-analysis-based-on-their-routes) and joined the Routes table to the Incidents table through **Joins and Relates > Join** and specifying **ObjectID, Routes, IncidentID** as follows:

[image]

This allowed me to then highlight those 'incidents' that recorded  under 'FacilityID' and then save those as a .SHP.

Not great, but it did the job.